# get values returned in URI in Ruby

Tags: ruby, url, uri

I want to get colours generated in http://coolors.co. It returns an URL like "http://coolors.co/f6494d-ff8559-ffce80-ffffff-b1ebf7". How to get the colour values and put them in variables?

Tried httparty and weary, but it didnt make too much sense. Would be glad if you could help!

Comment: please show the code you've tried to community, not many people like to develop solutions for someone from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `URI#split` method to get you something like this (thanks to tin man for the revision):

```
[10] pry(main)> path = URI("http://coolors.co/f6494d-ff8559-ffce80-ffffff-b1ebf7").path
=> "/f6494d-ff8559-ffce80-ffffff-b1ebf7"
[11] pry(main)> path[1..-1].split('-')
=> ["f6494d", "ff8559", "ffce80", "ffffff", "b1ebf7"]
```

Comment: Don't bother with `slice!(0)`, use `path[1..-1].split('a')`

Comment: Thanks Tin Man that looks good.  I think you meant `split('-')` anyways, I updated.

Comment: yes, but my path is coolors.co and I want it to visit(?) the url and add (random) colours, then get the uri and split it. sorry for being not clear at the beginning